# CodeIgniter Active Query behaves in an unexpected way

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have put the following code block to fetch items from database. Here is the code:

```
$db->where("type =", 1);
$db->where("status", 1);
$db->or_where("status", 2);
$db->order_by("id", "DESC");
$dbinfo = $db->get("ads")->result_array();
```

Now, based on the code above, it is expected to see the item whose type is 1, and whose status is 1, or is 2. But it fetches items whose types are also other than 1. This has made me confused from the early in the mornings. I do not know any more solution.

I also have printed out the generated CodeIgniter SQL query using the `$db->last_query()` for you to see and check.

```
SELECT * FROM (`ads`) WHERE `type` = '1' AND `status` = 1 OR `status` = 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using i.e added `(` `)`

```
`type` = '1' AND (`status` = 1 OR `status` = 2)
```

instead of

```
`type` = '1' AND `status` = 1 OR `status` = 2
```

Ref: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: $this->db->where('(status =1 OR status =2)', null, false);

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->or_where('id >', $id);`
`$db->where("type =", 1);`
`$db->where("status", 1);`
`$db->or_where("status >", 2);`
`$db->order_by("id", "DESC");`
`$dbinfo = $db->get("ads")->result_array();`